# CSS select multiple :last-of-type

Tags: css

Is it possible to target the two containers with the text "Highlight me" below with just CSS?

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="product">Bla</div>    
    <div class="product">Bla</div>    
    <div class="product">Highlight me!</div>
    <div class="more">
        <div class="product">Bla</div>    
        <div class="product">Bla</div>    
        <div class="product">Highlight me!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried it with `.product:last-of-type` but this only targets the nested element.

**Important:
I don't want to target the "Highlight me" containers with `:nth-child` as the number can vary.**

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ds4LY/)

Comment: wich container do you want to target ? `.more > .product` ?

Comment: **the two containers below** this is very confusing, there are many divs and a `div` can be called a container.

Comment: Come on guys isn't it obvious? Anyway I've edited my question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:last-of-type` will select only the last element found  .

here the last elements are `.more` and inside more the last `.product`.

`.more` doesn't match the selector, wich looks as well for a `.product` class

You could use : `.product:nth-child(3) {}`

http://jsfiddle.net/ds4LY/1/

---

**Another way to use , wich will match ,** `last-of-type` , is to use  `nth-last-of-type` 
http://jsfiddle.net/ds4LY/3/

```
.content .product:last-of-type,
.content > div:nth-last-of-type(2){
    border: red 1px solid;
}
```

---

some reading : http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-last-of-type/

Comment: @enyce12 will .more be always the last one , and will li all be with .product class ?

Comment: Yes, .more is always the last one and the containers will always have the class product (except the more container). Also the first "Highlight me" container will always be right in front of the more container and the second one will always be the last inside the more container.

Comment: Perfect, wasn't aware of `:nth-last-of-type()`. Thank you!

Comment: @enyce12 some reading if you like :) http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-last-of-type/

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the last child has always class of `more`. You want to select the div right above (with class of `product`) and the last `.product` inside `.more`. So you can do something like this:

```
.content > .product:nth-last-of-type(2), .content .product:last-of-type {
  border: red 1px solid;
}
```

That way the number of items can be various.

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/ds4LY/4/)

Comment: hehe , just did it :)

Comment: +1 for the correct answer but @GCyrillus was faster :)

Comment: I don't like this, I thought he was stuck at that :)

Comment: lol , +1 , i hardly get stuck with CSS, it is my playground :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can, try to separate more and content div's.. like this  **[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/ds4LY/2/)**

css:

```
.more > .product:last-of-type, .content > div.product:last-of-type {
    border: red 1px solid;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="product">Bla</div>
    <div class="product">Bla</div>
    <div class="product">Highlight me!</div></div>
    <div class="more">
        <div class="product">Bla</div>
        <div class="product">Bla</div>
        <div class="product">Highlight me!</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That's unfortunately not possible. I can't change the HTML structure.